# checking for multiple roles

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

so the bot gives role on reaction, i've made quite a few roles and catagories and some catagories you can only have one role from that catagory,
so i've been checking if the member has a role from the catagory with this code:

```
  if message_id == catagory1_id:

    if payload.emoji.name == "1️⃣":
      role = discord.utils.get(guild.roles, id=role1_id)
    elif payload.emoji.name == "2️⃣":
      role = discord.utils.get(guild.roles, id=role2_id)
    elif payload.emoji.name == "3️⃣":
      role = discord.utils.get(guild.roles, id=role3_id)
    else:
      role = None

    if role is not None:
      member = discord.utils.get(guild.members, id=payload.user_id)
      if member is not None:

        if role1 in member.roles:
          print('member has role1')

        elif female_role in member.roles:
          print('member has role2')

        elif female_role in member.roles:
          print('member has role3')

        else:
          await member.add_roles(role)
      else:
        Print('''couldn't get member''')
    else:
      Print('''couldn't get role''')
```

and it's making the code very long (1000+ just for role reactions) 
is there a neater way of doing this?

Comment: It's not quite clear to me what your objective is. Do you need a way to check if the member already has a role in a certain category? Or something else? Not quite clear as you have separate print statements for roles. You might've simplified it a bit too much for the sake of the example

Comment: sorry, i don't see a way to post a full code in the comments so i changed the code in the question to what the code would look like, i'm looking for a way to make the code shorter and easy to read

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems you're hardcoding a lot of things here, which would be ok if its meant to be a custom bot for a server I guess. As for how to make it more neat/readable I'd say iteration is your friend.

If I got it right your check for each incoming raw reaction if it is:

- A reaction to a certain message

then if it is

- A reaction of a set of reactions, that each have a linked role

then if

- The reactor already has a role in that category

This pattern of something(lets call it a key) being linked to a set of data sounds like it could use a dictionary to store. You can then iterate over that dictionary to check all the things you hardcoded now.

```py
reactionRolesDict = {
 *messageid1*: {
  "emotes": ["1️⃣", "2️⃣", "3️⃣"],
  "roles": [*role1_id*, *role2_id*, *role3_id*],
  "exclusive": True #(or false)
 },
 *messageid2*: {
 "emotes": ["1️⃣", "2️⃣", "3️⃣"],
 "roles": [*another_role1_id*, *another_role2_id*, *another_role3_id*],
 "exclusive": False
 },
}
```

etc, for every message you have that you have hardcoded rn you make a dictionary element like this. If you have more optional exceptions like only 1 role allowed(i called that exclusive) theres a few solutions to that

Now every time a reaction happens you iterate over it like:

```py
for category in reactionRolesDict:
 if messageid == category:
  category = reactionRolesDict[category]
  if payload.emoji.name in category["emotes"]:

   emoteIndex = category["emotes"].index("payload.emoji.name")
   role = discord.utils.get(guild.roles, id=category["roles"][emoteIndex])
   member = discord.utils.get(guild.members, id=payload.user_id)

   if category["exclusive"]: #if its not exclusive it'll skip this and just add it
    for role in category["roles"]:
     if role in member.roles:
      print(f"member already has {role.name}")
      break  #if the member has any of the roles in the category this will exit the on_raw_reaction_add() function

   await member.add_roles(role)
  else:
   print('''couldn't get role''')
```

Comment: wow, that is informative, now i need to go redo my whole code lol, thanks a lot for your help

Comment: sorry to bother you so late after, but i still get an error that i didn't find a solution for, as far as i understand it, it's saying that i'm trying to pass an integer as an array, the exception triggers at
 `if payload.emoji.name in category["emotes"]:` the error i get
 `TypeError: 'int' object is not subscriptable` even tho emotes catagory has only emojis `"emotes": ["♂️", "♀️", "1️⃣"],`

Comment: yes, forgive me for that. I typed it up without actually testing it myself. An overestimation of my own skill it seems. The issue is that the category variable is just the key of the message, not the setting for that message. It is easily fixed adding a line of `category = reactionRolesDict[category]`, ive also updated my answer

Comment: thank you so much for responding, i finally got the code working, i honestly wasn't expecting that you would responde, and again, sorry for bothering you so late

Comment: Well i get a notification about it, and time-wise its just afternoon for me haha

Answer (score 0):

I'd refactor using the `issubset()` [method](https://www.w3schools.com/python/ref_set_issubset.asp), and that way you could have it all in one `if` statement.

```py
if set([role1, role2, role3]).issubset(member.roles):
    print('member has role1, role2, and role3')
```

Comment: is there a way to get difftent outcome to for every role?

Comment: Ah, you want a better way to handle the individual roles? Apologies, thought you wanted to combine them.

Comment: no worries, sorry i didn't make that clear